# take over an existing (partially finished) Android project

Tags: android, maintenance, knowledge-transfer

I've been asked to takeover an existing Android project and the developer who was previously working on this project has left many things incomplete and un-solved with some really bad code documentation.

I am finding it difficult to understand the code and his coding standard and the previous developer can't be reached. What do I do now?

Any tips and tricks that can help me understand the existing project? What kind of docs should be made while developing (coding) for a project and what all documents the previous developer should have given me and please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are not experienced, and the ex-developer and his work cannot be that good too. Then try to have the old project running.

And start anew in a brand new project. Switching between both, considering what can be used. **Documenting** (which sources, what done) in a separate document, using version control. Try keep the code "clean" : something like model-view-controller, not overly complex.

Go for fast results, but of things you now have full confidence in. If a step needs more detailed improvements, consider whether you can do that later, and go to the next step. Document that. At the same time aim at perfection.

Being able to schematically pass all stations of the software is a large plus.

For the **business logic** consider small **unit tests** to develop (Test Driven Development). They need not be run on Androids.

As you have taken over an abandoned project, also document in prosa what you have done when in quite clear language. This is for the manager to have some insights, and be able to support you with respect to the rest of the organisation.

A total plan, of features, and a time schedule would be nice.

Communicate.